# Unable to use custom layer in AWS lambda (Ruby 3.2.0)

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I have a problem running a lambda (Runtime: Ruby 3.2) using a custom layer (pg gem).

I have followed the Ruby file structure as per [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path) to create the custom layer (.zip):

```
pg.zip
└ ruby/gems/3.2.0/
               | build_info
               | cache
               | doc
               | extensions
               | gems
               | └ pg-1.5.3
               └ specifications
                 └ pg-1.5.3.gemspec
```

This custom layer is already added in the lambda.

I tested and I got an error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "cannot load such file -- pg",
  "errorType": "Init<LoadError>",
  "stackTrace": [
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'",
    "/var/task/lambda_function.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'"
  ]
}
```

I built the package in Mac (x86_64) with `ruby@3.2` installed.

The ruby script works well when I ran it locally.

**Questions:**

1. Is my file structure for the pg.zip (custom layer) correct?
2. Or could this be a mismatch when bundling it in my current
   environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced a similar error too using lambda layers w ruby 3.2 runtimes!

To your qns:

1. Yes its correct usually! In our case, we will have an additional `lib` folder to store the native extensions.
2. Yes since `pg` depends on native extensions, you have to build the gem using in the same environment as the runtime environment.

These were the steps I took to solve it:

1. Build the gem `pg` using the lambda ruby 3.2 native extensions instead.

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/ruby:3.2

RUN yum install -y amazon-linux-extras \
    && amazon-linux-extras enable postgresql14 \
    && yum group install "Development Tools" -y

RUN yum install -y postgresql postgresql-devel

ADD Gemfile Gemfile.lock ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

ENV GEM_HOME=${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

RUN bundle config set without 'development test'
RUN bundle config set path 'vendor/bundle'

RUN bundle install
```

*Gemfile*

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'pg'
```

2. and then build the Dockerfile and copy the necessary extensions into the layer folder (i.e `$DIST_DIR` folder). Example script:

```bash
#!/bin/sh -e

rm -rf $DIST_DIR
mkdir -p "$DIST_DIR/lib"
mkdir -p "$DIST_DIR/ruby/gems"

cd "$SOURCE_DIR" >/dev/null || exit

docker build -t ruby-builder -f Dockerfile .
CONTAINER=$(docker run -d ruby-builder)

# See https://northsail.io/articles/aws-lambda-ruby-2-7-pg-gem-libldap-error
# for what to libpq binaries to copy for Amazon Linux 2
docker cp \
  $CONTAINER:/usr/lib64/libpq.so.5.14 \
  $DIST_DIR/lib/libpq.so.5

docker cp \
  $CONTAINER:/usr/lib64/libldap_r-2.4.so.2.10.7 \
  $DIST_DIR/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2

docker cp \
  $CONTAINER:/usr/lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2.10.7 \
  $DIST_DIR/lib/liblber-2.4.so.2

docker cp \
  $CONTAINER:/usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.3.0.0 \
  $DIST_DIR/lib/libsasl2.so.3

docker cp \
  $CONTAINER:/usr/lib64/libssl3.so \
  $DIST_DIR/lib/

docker cp \
  $CONTAINER:/usr/lib64/libsmime3.so \
  $DIST_DIR/lib/

docker cp \
  $CONTAINER:/usr/lib64/libnss3.so \
  $DIST_DIR/lib/

docker cp \
  $CONTAINER:/usr/lib64/libnssutil3.so \
  $DIST_DIR/lib/

docker cp \
  $CONTAINER:/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0 \
  $DIST_DIR/ruby/gems/3.2.0

docker stop $CONTAINER
docker rm $CONTAINER
```

The `docker cp` commands is used to copy over the [missing native extension files needed by `pg` gem](https://northsail.io/articles/aws-lambda-ruby-2-7-pg-gem-libldap-error) when running in the lambda environment which is running on Amazon Linux 2.

Your resulting layer contents should look like this:

```
├── lib
│   ├── liblber-2.4.so.2
│   ├── libldap_r-2.4.so.2
│   ├── libnss3.so
│   ├── libnssutil3.so
│   ├── libpq.so.5
│   ├── libsasl2.so.3
│   ├── libsmime3.so
│   └── libssl3.so
└── ruby
    └── gems
        └── 3.2.0
            ├── bin
            │   ├── bundle
            │   └── bundler
            ├── build_info
            ├── cache
            │   ├── bundler-2.4.6.gem
            │   └── pg-1.5.3.gem
            ├── doc
            ├── extensions
            │   └── aarch64-linux
            ├── gems
            │   ├── bundler-2.4.6
            │   └── pg-1.5.3
            ├── plugins
            └── specifications
                ├── bundler-2.4.6.gemspec
                └── pg-1.5.3.gemspec
```

3. .zip `$DIST_DIR` create a`ruby3.2` lambda layer using that same document you have: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/creating-deleting-layers.html

Comment: Thank you. Just a note for the future, if ruby3.2 will be using AL2023, `amazon-linux-extras` will no longer be available.

Comment: Do you set specific environment variables for the function that use the layer ? I have build a layer and assigned it to the function, but when "pg" is required, it does not find the native extensions in `lib/`. Thanks.

Comment: @aurels what does your layer file structure look like? is lib/ within the layer .zip file?

Comment: @houdinisparks Same as you but I've just found my issue : I was building on a M2 mac and then the SO were for ARM. I had to force amd64 ! Thanks.