# AWS Lambda Layer for Ruby Postgres gem not working

Tags: ruby, postgresql, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I'm trying to build a Postgres layer for an AWS Lambda running on Ruby using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76717413/unable-to-use-custom-layer-in-aws-lambda-ruby-3-2-0) as a guide but it's not working.

This is the Dockerfile. I've added `RUN bundle config cache_all true` and `RUN bundle package` in an attempt to make this work. I've also tried `RUN env ARCHFLAGS="-arch aarch64" gem install pg` and still didn't work.

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/ruby:3.2

RUN yum install -y amazon-linux-extras \
    && amazon-linux-extras enable postgresql14 \
    && yum group install "Development Tools" -y

RUN yum install -y postgresql postgresql-devel

ADD Gemfile Gemfile.lock ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

ENV GEM_HOME=${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

RUN bundle config cache_all true
RUN bundle config set path 'vendor/bundle'

RUN bundle install
RUN bundle package
```

This is the script

```
#!/bin/sh -e

DIST_DIR="pg"
rm -rf $DIST_DIR
mkdir -p "$DIST_DIR/lib"
mkdir -p "$DIST_DIR/ruby/gems"

cd "$SOURCE_DIR" >/dev/null || exit

docker build -t ruby-builder -f Dockerfile .
CONTAINER=$(docker run -d ruby-builder)

# See https://northsail.io/articles/aws-lambda-ruby-2-7-pg-gem-libldap-error
# for what to libpq binaries to copy for Amazon Linux 2
docker cp \
  $CONTAINER:/usr/lib64/libpq.so.5.14 \
  $DIST_DIR/lib/libpq.so.5

docker cp \
  $CONTAINER:/usr/lib64/libldap_r-2.4.so.2.10.7 \
  $DIST_DIR/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2

docker cp \
  $CONTAINER:/usr/lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2.10.7 \
  $DIST_DIR/lib/liblber-2.4.so.2

docker cp \
  $CONTAINER:/usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.3.0.0 \
  $DIST_DIR/lib/libsasl2.so.3

docker cp \
  $CONTAINER:/usr/lib64/libssl3.so \
  $DIST_DIR/lib/

docker cp \
  $CONTAINER:/usr/lib64/libsmime3.so \
  $DIST_DIR/lib/

docker cp \
  $CONTAINER:/usr/lib64/libnss3.so \
  $DIST_DIR/lib/

docker cp \
  $CONTAINER:/usr/lib64/libnssutil3.so \
  $DIST_DIR/lib/

docker cp \
  $CONTAINER:/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0 \
  $DIST_DIR/ruby/gems/3.2.0

docker stop $CONTAINER
docker rm $CONTAINER
```

The generated folder tree looks like this:

```
.
├── lib
└── ruby
    └── gems
        └── 3.2.0
            ├── bin
            ├── build_info
            ├── cache
            ├── doc
            ├── extensions
            │   └── aarch64-linux
            │       └── 3.2.0
            ├── gems
            │   ├── bundler-2.4.17
            │   │   ├── exe
            │   │   └── lib
            │   └── pg-1.5.4
            │       ├── certs
            │       ├── ext
            │       ├── lib
            │       ├── misc
            │       ├── rakelib
            │       ├── sample
            │       └── translation
            ├── plugins
            └── specifications
```

This is the lambda function to test if the gem in the layer is working:

```
require 'json'
require 'pg'

def lambda_handler(event:, context:)
    { statusCode: 200, body: {postgres_client_version: PG.library_version}.to_json }
end
```

And this is the error message:

```
Test Event Name
test

Response
{
  "errorMessage": "cannot load such file -- pg",
  "errorType": "Init<LoadError>",
  "stackTrace": [
    "<internal:/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:86:in `require'",
    "<internal:/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:86:in `require'",
    "/var/task/lambda_function.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'",
    "<internal:/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:86:in `require'",
    "<internal:/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:86:in `require'"
  ]
}

Function Logs
Ignoring pg-1.5.4 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine pg --version 1.5.4
Init error when loading handler lambda_function.lambda_handler
{
  "errorMessage": "cannot load such file -- pg",
  "errorType": "Init<LoadError>",
  "stackTrace": [
    "<internal:/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:86:in `require'",
    "<internal:/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:86:in `require'",
    "/var/task/lambda_function.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'",
    "<internal:/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:86:in `require'",
    "<internal:/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:86:in `require'"
  ]
}
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 324.56 ms    Phase: init Status: error   Error Type: Runtime.ExitError
Ignoring pg-1.5.4 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine pg --version 1.5.4
Init error when loading handler lambda_function.lambda_handler
{
  "errorMessage": "cannot load such file -- pg",
  "errorType": "Init<LoadError>",
  "stackTrace": [
    "<internal:/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:86:in `require'",
    "<internal:/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:86:in `require'",
    "/var/task/lambda_function.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'",
    "<internal:/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:86:in `require'",
    "<internal:/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:86:in `require'"
  ]
}
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 2500.61 ms   Phase: invoke   Status: error   Error Type: Runtime.ExitError
START RequestId: 2ab0555b-bde9-4cb1-a0d4-ee0d2fe2d0b1 Version: $LATEST
Unknown application error occurred
Runtime.Unknown
END RequestId: 2ab0555b-bde9-4cb1-a0d4-ee0d2fe2d0b1
REPORT RequestId: 2ab0555b-bde9-4cb1-a0d4-ee0d2fe2d0b1  Duration: 2520.07 ms    Billed Duration: 2521 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 16 MB
```

It would seem that the native extensions for PG are not being installed or are being installed for a different architecture but I can't figure out how to fix it and at this point and pretty much confused.

Any pointers on how to make this work will be greatly appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It worked after using a different Docker Image:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/sam/build-ruby3.2:latest-x86_64
```

Apparently the previous one had a different architecture and was installing incorrect dependencies.